# Converting SQL to Linq with groupby, sum and count

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I would like to do a group by and on that a sum and a count. I don't seem to be able to create the solution in linq. How can I convert my query to linq?

```
SELECT HistoricalBillingProductGroup, 
        COUNT(*), 
        BillingPeriod, 
        SUM(TotalMonthlyChargesOtcAndMrc)
FROM [x].[dbo].[tblReport]
group by BillingPeriod, HistoricalBillingProductGroup
order by BillingPeriod
```

This is what I got sofar in Linq

```
var result =
    context.Reports.GroupBy(x => new {x.BillingPeriod, x.HistoricalBillingProductGroup})
            .Select(x => new StatisticsReportLine
                {
                    HistoricalBillingGroup = x.FirstOrDefault().HistoricalBillingProductGroup,
                    BillingPeriod = x.FirstOrDefault().BillingPeriod,
                    CountOfRows = x.Count(),
                    SumOfAmount = x.Sum(p => p.TotalMonthlyChargesOtcAndMrc) ?? 0
                })
            .ToString();
```

The query I get from this is enormous and takes a very long time to load. In SQL its a matter of milliseconds. I hardly doubt this is the solution.

Comment: What is the type of `context.Reports`? Have you looked at the generated SQL?

Comment: I get reports form my code first domain context, the generated SQL is like the answer says with a few sub queries. That's what makes it slow I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the calls to `x.FirstOrDefault()` are the source of your problem. Each one of these will result in a very costly inner query inside the `SELECT` clause of the generated SQL.

Try using the [`Key`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb343251%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property of the `IGrouping<T>` instead :

```
var result = context.Reports
    .GroupBy(x => new {x.BillingPeriod, x.HistoricalBillingProductGroup})
    .OrderBy(x => x.Key.BillingPeriod)
    .Select(x => new StatisticsReportLine
        {
            HistoricalBillingProductGroup = x.Key.HistoricalBillingProductGroup,
            BillingPeriod = x.Key.BillingPeriod,
            CountOfRows = x.Count(),
            SumOfAmount = x.Sum(p => p.TotalMonthlyChargesOtcAndMrc) ?? 0
        });
```

Or if you prefer query syntax:

```
var result =
    (from r in context.Reports
     group r by new { r.BillingPeriod, r.HistoricalBillingProductGroup } into g
     orderby g.Key.BillingPeriod
     select new StatisticsReportLine
     {
         HistoricalBillingProductGroup = g.Key.HistoricalBillingProductGroup,
         BillingPeriod = g.Key.BillingPeriod,
         CountOfRows = g.Count(),
         SumOfAmount = x.Sum(p => p.TotalMonthlyChargesOtcAndMrc) ?? 0
     });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, personally I prefer the non query syntax.

Comment: @Freddy No problem. I prefer the fluent syntax for very short queries, and the query syntax for longer, more complex queries, but it's really a matter of taste. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

You could try this one:

```
var result = context.Reports
                    .GroupBy(x => new {x.BillingPeriod, x.HistoricalBillingProductGroup})
                    .Select(x => new StatisticsReportLine
                    {
                        HistoricalBillingGroup = x.Key.HistoricalBillingProductGroup,
                        BillingPeriod = x.Key.BillingPeriod,
                        CountOfRows = x.Count(),
                        SumOfAmount = x.Sum(p => p.TotalMonthlyChargesOtcAndMrc) ?? 0
                    }).ToString();
```

In the above query you make a group by on two properties, `BillingPeriod` and `HistoricalBillingProductGroup`. So in each group that will be created, you will have a key, that will be consisted by these two properties.